# [Android]adding checkbox to images in grid view

Tags: android, gridview, view, inflate

Xml for the Grid layout.

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/myGrid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="2dip"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="148dp"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

imagenselect.xml for Image and checkbox.

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/GridItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#000080">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ImageView>
 <CheckBox 
     android:id="@+id/check1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Android" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Class for adding the images in gridview and displaying,

```
private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        public ImageAdapter(Context localcontext){  
            context = localcontext;
        }
        public int getCount() { 
            return cursor.getCount();
        } 

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
        }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub\

    View MyView = convertView;
    ImageView picturesView;
    picturesView = new ImageView(context);

    if (convertView == null) {

     LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
     MyView =  li.inflate(R.layout.imagenselect, null);

    // Move cursor to current position
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    // Get the current value for the requested column
    int imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
    // Set the content of the image based on the provided URI
        picturesView.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(
    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageID));

    picturesView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    picturesView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    picturesView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));           
        }
    else {
         picturesView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    return picturesView;
      }
    }
}
```

Here with this code , I get only the images in gridview. But i want to inflate the view and use it such that i'm able to add a checkbox along with the image. (for each image a checkbox).

### Since there are two views in the function  "myView" and "picturesView". If i try to typecast the picturesView to myView then i'm getting a crash. Thanks in advance !

on changing as u suggested im getting a crash.

```
        @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub\

        View myView = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
           LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
           myView =  li.inflate(R.layout.imagenselect, null);
            }
        ImageView picturesView;
        picturesView = new ImageView(context);
               picturesView = (ImageView) myView.findViewById( R.id.grid_item_image);

        // Move cursor to current position
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        // Get the current value for the requested column
        int imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
        // Set the content of the image based on the provided URI
        picturesView.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(
              MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageID));

        picturesView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        picturesView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        picturesView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));               

        return myView;
    }
```

---

Comment: Please post details of the crash, ideally the logcat output which shows the excpetion being thrown.

Comment: The above posted code doesnt crash, It only crashes if i typecast one view to another. With the above code i get only the images, now im trying to add the checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code actually looks really confused to me. Your code **always** returns an `ImageView` object, and never the `MyView` view that you inflate from your layout which contains your check box. That would explain why your check box is not appearing.

I think that you need something along the lines of:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View myView = convertView
    if( myView == null )
    {
        LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
        myView = li.inflate(R.layout.imagenselect, null);
    }
    ImageView pictureView = (ImageView) myView.findViewById( R.id.grid_item_image );
    // initialise pictureView here.
    return myView;
}
```

Comment: Well, if you return an ImageView object, your checkbox will not appear in your ListView item. If you return the View that you inflate from your imagenselect layout, you will get a LinearLayout containing both an ImageView object and a CheckBox object. In your question you say that you cannot work out why your CheckBox is not appearing, but the view that you are returning does not contain a CheckBox. In the answer above I show you how you should be doing things to return a view which consists of a LinearLayout which contains both an ImageView and a CheckBox.

Comment: Please provide details of the crash.

Comment: Thank you Mark !I get the image and checkbox. But if i have the following line it crashes. picturesView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));

Comment: Rather than doing it programatically, why not set this in your layout XML by adding `android:layout_width="100dp"` and `android:layout_height="100dp"`?

Comment: Now i added a checkbox to the imagenselect.xml and i'm able to see the checkbox. But if i select(check mark) say 2 items in a grid view . And then i scroll down , i see some other 2 images also got selected. This is strange . Any ideas ?

Comment: I don't know without seeing the current version of your code and knowing how you are implementing the ID of each list item. Maybe this is a new question?